# Why isn't data I wanna connected User model connected to the model?

Tags: python, django, excel

I wanna parse excel and put it to the model(User) which has same user_id of dictionary. I wrote

```
#coding:utf-8
from django.shortcuts import render
import xlrd
from .models import User

book = xlrd.open_workbook('../data/excel1.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(1)

def build_employee(employee):
  if employee == 'leader':
     return 'l'
  if employee == 'manager':
     return 'm'
  if employee == 'others':
     return 'o'

for row_index in range(sheet.nrows):
  rows = sheet.row_values(row_index) 
  is_man = rows[4] != ""
  emp = build_employee(rows[5])
  user = User(user_id=rows[1], name_id=rows[2], name=rows[3], 
              age=rows[4],man=is_man,employee=emp)
  user.save()


files = glob.glob('./user/*.xlsx')

data_dict_key ={}
for x in files:
   if "$" not in x:
      book3 = xlrd.open_workbook(x)
      sheet3 = book3.sheet_by_index(0)
      cells = [
    ('company_id', 0, 4),
    ('user_id', 0, 5),
    ('name', 0, 6),
            ]
      data_dict = OrderedDict()
      for key, rowy, colx in cells:
          try:
              data_dict[key] = sheet3.cell_value(rowy, colx)
          except IndexError:
              data_dict[key] = None

       if data_dict['user_id'] in data_dict_key:

          data_dict_key[data_dict['user_id']].update(data_dict)
                       continue
       data_dict[data_dict_key['user_id']] = data_dict
       for row_number, row_data in data_dict_key.items():
           user1 = User.filter(user_id=row_data['user_id']).exists()
           if user1:
              user1.__dict__.update(**data_dict_key)
              user1.save()
```

db.sqlite3 has data in this part

```
User(user_id=rows[1], name_id=rows[2], name=rows[3], 
              age=rows[4],man=is_man,employee=emp)
```

and in this part

```
user1.__dict__.update(**data_dict_key)
```

separately.
I wanna save these part data together in having same user_id in this part

```
User.filter(user_id=row_data['user_id']).exists()
```

so I really cannot understand why I cannot do it.No error happens,so I do not have a clue.What is wrong in my code?How should I fix this?
models.py is

```
#coding:utf-8
from django.db import models
class User(models.Model):
    company_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Comment: One day I'm going to work out what schools are teaching that "wanna" is an acceptable abbreviation in written English. It really isn't.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: don't you mean "One day I'm gunna work out..."

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
user1 = User.filter(user_id=row_data['user_id']).exists()
```

looks wrong for two reasons:

- `filter()` needs to be called on the manager, not the model instance,
- `exists()` returns a bool

This code should be raising an exception due to the incorrect use of `filter()`, but as it is not, it appears that that line is not being executed. The reason for that is because `data_dict_key` is empty and therefore the body of the final for loop is not entered. Finally the reason that `data_dict_key` is empty is because of the `if` statement in this code:

```
   if data_dict['user_id'] in data_dict_key:
      data_dict_key[data_dict['user_id']].update(data_dict)
```

`data_dict_key` is initialised to `{}` before the main loop, and so it will never contain a key for the user id.

Comment: I cannot understand the meaning of filter() needs to be called on the manager, not the model instance.Could u write the codes ?

Comment: @user8504021: it is basic Django model usage. Have you read the tutorial? Your code should be `user1 = User.objects.filter(user_id=row_data['user_id'])`. N.B. the addition of `objects`. Then you need to check whether you got a result (a simple `if user1:` should do it).

Comment: I added objects to the codes and I found user1 was gotten,but data cannot be connected.What should I do to fix this?

Comment: @user8504021: Did you also fix the problem with the empty dictionary?